# Click custom multi commands together with bash completion

Tags: python-3.x, python-click

I followed the example in Click documentation for implementing
[custom multi commands](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#custom-multi-commands) and then I want to combine this with Bash completion support as described [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/bashcomplete/). The result when I try to complete using TAB is that "cli" is inserted after my program name instead of the custom commands...

```
$ mycommand <Press TAB 2x>
$ mycommand cli
```

Not that none of my custom multi commands are named "cli".

Is there any way around this?

(Copy of custom multi command example code below)

```
import click
import os

plugin_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'commands')

class MyCLI(click.MultiCommand):

    def list_commands(self, ctx):
        rv = []
        for filename in os.listdir(plugin_folder):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                rv.append(filename[:-3])
        rv.sort()
        return rv

    def get_command(self, ctx, name):
        ns = {}
        fn = os.path.join(plugin_folder, name + '.py')
        with open(fn) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), fn, 'exec')
            eval(code, ns, ns)
        return ns['cli']

cli = MyCLI(help='This tool\'s subcommands are loaded from a '
            'plugin folder dynamically.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems important for click autocompletion to name your sub-command as like this:

```py
@click.command(name="<YOUR_CMD_NAME>")
```

Then all you have to do is to set right env var as explained in the [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/bashcomplete/#activation).

> `eval "$(_FOO_BAR_COMPLETE=source_bash foo-bar)"`

Comment: Just a note on the documentation for anyone who arrives here after me, they renamed "source_bash" to "bash_source" in 8.x (might save someone else 30 minutes of debugging).

Answer (score 0):

My case is using group as subgroup, and the name default is 'cli'.
Assign name for the group. "ns['cli'].name = name"
try this:

```
def get_command(self, ctx, name):
    ns = {}
    fn = os.path.join(plugin_folder, name + '.py')
    with open(fn) as f:
        code = compile(f.read(), fn, 'exec')
        eval(code, ns, ns)
    ns['cli'].name = name
    return ns['cli']
```